# How to build multi-level datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid

I'm using Entity Framework 6 with my C# WPF application and want to show my data in a multi-level datagrid.

My dataset contains 2 simple entities:

- Projects: Id, ParentId (nullable), Name
- Tasks: Id, ProjectId, Name

So every task is attached to one project. And every project can have an optional parent project. This leads to a hierarchical structure of n levels.
Corresponding navigation properties are already in place (Project.ParentProject, Task.Project).

**What I have tried so far:**

1. Use Tasks as CollectionViewSource and group by Project. With the use of an IValueConverter I was able to iterate through all parents and write it in a single group row like this: 'Project-1 / Project 1.1 / Project 1.1.1'. The disadvantage is that there is no hierarchy in my datagrid and empty projects will not show up.
2. Use Projects as CollectionViewSource - this will show all projects. But neither figured I out how to build a hierarchy nor how to show the tasks as childs.

**The expected outcome would be something like this:**

- Project-1

  - Project-1.1

    - Task-100
- Project-2

  - Project-2.1

    - Task-200
  - Project-2.2

So every project is shown in its hierarchy even if there are no tasks. At a later point, it would be nice to have the option to hide all empty projects and only show projects (and their parent projects) with tasks.

So has anyone a clue on how to do this? Appreciate your input and ideas!

Comment: That's a grid in "tree view".  Unless you're ready for a major undertaking, I'd be looking for a 3rd party control to do this.  However, recommendations are off-topic for SO.

Comment: You can use ListView with Custom Templates but it may not give you DataGrid Out Of Box feature.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [RowDetailsTemplate](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/details-row/)

You can place a new `datagrid` within this template and it will do what you want to achieve.

Comment: Do you mean I should use RowDetails for the Task rows? How would I build the structure for the Project rows then?

Comment: Yes, assuming that the Task Rows collection is a child property of a Project row, you can bind the new DataGrid's (the one within the `RowDetailsTemplate`) ItemsSource to the Project Row's child property/collection "Task Rows".

Comment: I know that binding that way would work for the Task rows but how would I build the tree for the Project rows?